# When google offers preview images of sites, do they store those images in their database?

Tags: database, image, google-search

Google has an option that if you click the magnifying glass next to a search result, it shows you an image of the page.

Does google store these images in their database? On their filesystem? Or are they generated dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually base64 encodes of the images, rather than pointers or the image itself.

Comment: +1 After realizing what the question meant I did find out they are base64 by checking the properties of the image.  +1 to @Dan.

Comment: and this is stored in the database? how do they generate these images?

Comment: Hard to say where they store them - DB or flat files but could be anything. You can use php to base64 encode or the language/framework of your choice - [Base64 Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: @Dan @JonH do you think they crawled the web to generate all of these images? or that they wait for the site to appear in a search result and then dynamically fetch the image?

Comment: They definitely doubt they image on the fly, there would be too much overhead those images are pre collected results. It would make sense to crawl the web as usual (they are pretty good at it) and create those encodes for retrieval later.

Comment: @Dan yeah I figured. If I'm using the google web search API to provide search results and also wanted to provide image previews, how would you suggest I do it? I don't think the API gives you access to the images (I have not found it in the docs).

Comment: If they don't provide it in the API (I'm not familiar) then it'll be a tricky one as you'll have to maintain your own dataset.